# PHP SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I am getting this error when connection to database but i can't seem to find the reason.

```
 Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
    (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:635)Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
    (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:635)0
```

I've checked the listener and there's nothing wrong there, i also can use Toad and SQL Developer with no issue. Furthermore, i've tried put the php page in my other local machine and no error like this occurred. Here's the connection.php:

```
   $tns="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.10)(PORT = 1528)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = XE)))";
    $oracleUser = 'ADMIN';
    $oraclePass = 'ADMIN';
    try {
        $oracle = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns, $oracleUser, $oraclePass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE));
        $oracle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $oracle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,  PDO::CASE_LOWER);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The funny thing is, the error only appear every time i try to login to my page, then after i refresh the page, the error is no more. I'm running out of things to try, i hope someone can help, thank you.

Comment: hey Shira check this out one of the possible reason  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970158/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred

Comment: @SeanCh Well, i've checked that too, and still have the problem. For now i'll try to re-install the Oracle Client and the middleware, since maybe the ORAHOME is bugged.