# ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred - server connect to DB

Tags: database, oracle, firewall, tns

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!!!**

I am receiving the below:

ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred when trying to connect to a database using sqlplus from one server to another.

tnsping for the connect alias works, no issues.

telnet using the cluster alias and the listener port in the tns entry works fine.

Just trying to actually connect via sqlplus results in a time out

I don't suspect the firewall, because like I say, telnet works.

This is a 3 node RAC.

Any ideas what might be stopping the connection?

(I have searched this site and others and there is no suitable identical similar question / answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970158/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred)

Comment: Thanks but this is definitely different

Comment: Does the listener log show anything?  Given the debugging you've done so far, I'd suggest you do a sqlnet client trace.  Set the proper parameters in the client-side sqlnet.ora.  See the relevent SQLNET Admin Guide for details.