# ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred in pycharm

Tags: oracle

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970158/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred) and a variety of other links online but don't understand. I am trying to connect to our oracle databases in python, specifically pycharm. I am just a business user and the only oracle tool installed on my machine is instantclient_19_5. I am trying to connect to our database in this manner:

```
import cx_Oracle
import os

LOCATION = r"C:\Users\CN196483\PycharmProjects\recon\venv\oracle\instantclient_19_5"
os.environ["PATH"] = LOCATION + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]

dsnName = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host=host,port=port,service_name=servicename)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=USR,password=PASS,dsn=dsnName)
```

And am obviously met with

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

All the resources I have read say things like checking the firewall, checking IP addresses in the tnsnames.ora file, issuing lsnrctl status commands, etc. But I don't think I have access to any of these as a business user do I? I understand those to be on the dba side.

Is there anything I can do about this? Does it have anything to do with my setup of the instant client?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure, all the parameters (host, port, servicename, usr, pass, dsnName) are replaced with actual values in your real code?

Comment: Yes, definitely. And they have all been confirmed as accurate.