# Why does telnet connect to database but cx-oracle won't?

Tags: python, oracle, telnet, cx-oracle

When I run the below command it works fine.

```
telnet hostname port
```

But when I try the below code from the same machine I get an error.

```
import cx_Oracle

cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, hostname:port/service_name)
```

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

I am able to connect to a different Oracle database using the same code.

I am able to connect to the database from a different machine using Oracle SQL Developer.

The database has 3 mirrored servers with 3 IP addresses and hostnames. I have tried all the IP addresses and hostnames along with the common hostname (which I'm assuming automatically resolves to one of the mirrored servers).

Can you please tell me what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: There is a good a discussion related to `ORA-12170` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970158/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred

Comment: Thanks but I have looked at it already and that does not help my case.

Comment: Turns out that a couple of VIPs needed to be added to the network and security ACL. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: PSK, i have the firewalld stopped and still cant connect, ¿What exactly have you do to to disable these ACLs? thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help much here because my organisation's network and security teams sorted this out for me. Their suggestion was that when everything seems right but you still can't connect to a database then you must be blocked by some security layer. I suggest you ask a new question with more details about your particular case and someone may be able to help.