# Timeout error while trying to connect to a remote Oracle Database in Python using cx_Oracle within a virtual environment

Tags: python, timeout, database-connection, cx-oracle

So I'm trying to establish a connection to a remote Oracle Database in python, from a Linux CentOS machine, but I'm getting the error-

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout
```

occurred.

I'm using a virtual environment to run my code, wherein I have installed the **cx-Oracle==8.3.0.**
My python version is **3.6.2** and below is my code

```
import cx_Oracle

username ="username"
password ="password"

tns_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("examplehost.com", 1528, "SID")

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
                username,
                password,
                tns_dsn)

print(connection.version)
```

I've also tried
`connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@examplehost.com:1528/SID")` and possibly many other ways of connecting to the database, all have given me the same error.

I read other similar questions, some said to modify tnsnames.ora which I can't find anywhere on the system, as I'm using a virtual to implement this.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong or if I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Look at answers to other posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970158/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred

Comment: Also look at upgrading Python, since 3.6 is not supported by upstream.  And upgrade cx_Oracle, see the latest [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).